# How to type a React component definition?

Tags: typescript, reactjs

I am trying to statically type the props of a React component. After including the [definitions for React](https://github.com/wizzard0/react-typescript-definitions/blob/master/react.d.ts), I have defined a typed variation of `React.createClass` named `component`.

```
interface Component<P> {
    (props: P, ...children: any[]): React.ReactComponent<P, any>
}

function component<P, S>(spec: React.ReactComponentSpec<P, S>): Component<P> {
    return React.createClass(spec);
}
```

When I define a `Label` Component with an annotation that says that it takes a `text` string prop,

```
var Label: Component<{text: string}> = component({
    render: function() {
        return React.DOM.div(null, this.props.text);
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return React.DOM.div(null, Label({text: "Hello"}));
    }
});
```

the compiler checks that `Label` is called with a `text` property and that it is a string.

The next step is to have the compiler check `this.props.text` uses *inside* the `Label` methods. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [react-typescript](https://github.com/fdecampredon/react-typescript) bridge, which defines a base class which can be used from TypeScript:

```
class HelloMessage extends ReactTypescript.ReactComponentBase<{ name: string; }, {}> {
  render() {
    return React.DOM.div(null, 'Hello ' + this.props.name);
  }
}
```

Since the base class is generic, `this.props` is properly typed as `{ name: string; }` in the example above.

Comment: There was a bug in the past which caused me issues when using the React debug tools in Chrome, and when returning ReactComponentBase components from the render method of other ReactComponentBase components, but I've not gotten around to submitting those fixes yet... if you have any problems with the latest version I can dig out the changes I made.

Comment: After some more testing, componentDidMount does not work. Do you see the same behaviour?

Comment: No, not seen that, and I have used that to hook up window resize handlers. If render is being called, I'd expect other overrides to be called too.

Comment: Warning to any new folks coming to this post - this answer is really, really out of date.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, you want to create interfaces for your Props and State and pass them as the type of new class which extends `React.Component`. Using the React type definition means that you don't have to add types for anything other than the new classes you're creating. You can see this done in the pattern below.

(I wrote a blog post about this [here](http://www.austentalbot.com/how-to-use-react-with-typescript/))

```
/// <reference path='../typings/react/react.d.ts' />
import React = require('react');

interface P {
  name?: string;
}

interface S {
  complete?: boolean;
}

class Goal extends React.Component<P, S> {
  state: S = {
    complete: false
  }

  private _toggleCompletion = () => {
    this.setState({complete: !this.state.complete});
  }

  render() {
    var status = 'Status: ' + (this.state.complete ? 'complete' : 'incomplete');
    return React.DOM.div({
      children: [
        React.DOM.div({}, this.props.name + ' - ' + status),
        React.DOM.button({
          onClick: this._toggleCompletion
        }, 'Toggle completion')
      ]
    });
  }
}

React.render(React.createElement(Goal, {name: 'Learn React and TypeScript'}), document.getElementById('react'));
```